# Evaluating multiple ranges within an Oracle IN clause

Tags: oracle, between, range

I have an Oracle select that looks like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM CUSTOMER
 WHERE (CUSTOMER_TYPE BETWEEN 100 AND 200
     OR CUSTOMER_TYPE = 350
     OR CUSTOMER_TYPE BETWEEN 410 AND 520);
```

I want to change it to something that combines the evaluation of multiple ranges and individual values within the same statement.  The below syntax is NOT CORRECT, but is there some Oracle equivalent?

```
SELECT *
  FROM CUSTOMER
 WHERE CUSTOMER_TYPE IN (100..200, 350, 410..520);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it? What are you looking to gain here?

Comment: Ummm... As far as I know you're already doing this optimally. Why do you wan to change?

Comment: I think author want to have both individual numbers and number ranges in a string, so it can be read from a variable (or file).

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as a possibility.

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER c,
(
    select level + 99 n from dual connect by level < 102
        union all
    select 350 n from dual
        union all
    select level + 409 n from dual connect by level < 112
) t
WHERE c.CUSTOMER_TYPE = t.n
```

It avoids the **OR**, and the **IN**.  If you are lucky a **hash join** is the result.

Comment: This is an equally accurate way of doing this but I fail to see the benefit. You're still doing the same index range scan (assuming it's indexed) but you're generating the range in SQL rather than internally , which'll be slower.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid BETWEEN because it requires multiple OR statement if I'm evaluating a non-sequential range of numbers. I just want to know if there is an easier 'short-hand' way to evaluate a range of numbers.  Other languages allow "100..200" as short-hand for "between 100 and 200".  My actual query is much larger with many BETWEEN/OR statements.  Dose Oracle have an equivalent short-hand for BETWEEN

Comment: @GreggFeldt, _whatever_ you do, _however_ you do it, you want data from several ranges. This in turn means that you have to use a logical OR. No matter what language you use it will still be the same. Why does syntax matter? Is your current query not efficient enough?

Comment: It's not a matter of efficiency, just ease of writing when evaluating multiple ranges.  I'm coming to the conclusion that I'll have to stick with BETWEEN/OR.